# Why Netbeans doesn't pick up on Maven proxy settings

Tags: macos, maven, netbeans, proxy, download

I am using Mac's OSX 10.9.2 and trying to create a Maven project with NetBeans 7.2.1 and Maven 3.1.1

In NetBeans I setup the proxy settings correctly in "Preferences->General->Proxy Settings".

In `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.1.1/conf/settings.xml` I setup the Proxy settings correctly.

It works in the CLI, hen I download the repo, e.g.:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

but if I try to create a project in NetBeans, it doesn't work and I get the error:

> Scanning for projects... Downloading:
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
>   Aug 04, 2014 6:16:42 PM
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector
>   tryConnect INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when
>   connecting to the target host: Network is unreachable Aug 04, 2014
>   6:16:42 PM
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector
>   tryConnect INFO: Retrying connect

Why doesn't NetBeans pick up on the Maven proxy settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, netbeans by default uses maven 3.0.5 from it's own installation. Not your 3.1.1, unless you specify it to be used in Tools/Options/Java/Maven. conf/settings.xml is private to given maven installation, while ~/.m2 contains your user settings.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that NetBeans creates a .m2/ directory under your user and downloads the repo into that directry.

I went into .m2/ and created a link from it to the file `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.1.1/conf/settings.xml`

```
ln -s  /usr/local/apache-maven-3.1.1/conf/settings.xml settings.xml
```

Following that the download works.

Answer (score 2):

For Netbeans Maven setting needs proxy setting if you are running you system under proxy network.

Open following file:`NETBEANS_HOME\java\maven\conf\settings.xml`

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
   <active>true</active>
   <host>myproxy.host.net</host>
     <port>80</port>
   </proxy>
 </proxies>
```

Note: Netbeans IDE have it self separate configuration what we see in first opening welcome page

Comment: my NETBEANS_HOME was C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\

Answer (score 1):

To add proxy in Netbeans's default Maven:

Edit settings.xml in netbeans.home/java/maven/conf

In my machine it is - /home/raman/netbeans-8.0.2/java/maven/conf

Add your proxy like below:

```
<proxies>
<!-- Some bank proxy -->
<proxy>
    <id>optional</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <username>test</username>
    <password>test123</password>
    <host>192.168.137.15</host>
    <port>8080</port>
    <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
</proxies>
```